# QMap retrieve last added record data

Tags: qt

I have following data method:

```
/**
 * @brief UeOrdersModel::ueSlotRefreshOrdersData
 * @return  bool (true - success, false - error)
 */
bool UeOrdersModel::ueSlotRefreshOrdersData()
{
    QString userId=QString();
    QString placeId=QString();
    QString customerId=QString();
    bool result=false;

    if(this->ueLoggedUsersInfo()->ueNumberOfLoggedUsers()>0)
    {
        QMap<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>::const_iterator iterator=this->ueLoggedUsersInfo()->ueLoggedUsersData()->constBegin();
        userId=iterator.key().first();
        placeId=iterator.key().second();
        customerId=iterator.value();

        if(this->ueRefreshOrdersData(userId,
                                     placeId,
                                     customerId))
        {
            result=true;
        }   // if
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // ueSlotRefreshOrdersData
```

Now, this method's purpose is to issue some `SQL` statement with three parameters: **userId**, **placeId** and **customerId**, all of them are of type `QString`. However, data itself for these three parameters is packed into `QMap<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>` data structure - the key is represented by `QPair` of **userId** and **placeId**, **customerId** is packed as `QMap` value (3rd `QString`). If I try to compile this method, I get following errors:

```
../../database/ueordersmodel.cpp: In member function 'bool UeOrdersModel::ueSlotRefreshOrdersData()': ../../database/ueordersmodel.cpp:906:37: error: no match for call to '(const QString) ()'
         userId=iterator.key().first();
                                     ^ ../../database/ueordersmodel.cpp:907:39: error: no match for call to '(const QString) ()'
         placeId=iterator.key().second();
```

Why and how do I get rid of them? I am trying to fetch data from `QMap` into three `QString`s.

P.S.: The second question is maybe offtopic, but since is somehow connected to problem, I will ask it here: If I do `insert()` - insert record into `QMap`, the last record added is on top or on bottom of data structure?

Comment: It should be rather `iterator.key().first;` and not `iterator.key().first();`. The same for the `iterator.key().second;`

Comment: @vahancho LOL, it is `first` and `second` are member variables, not methods. Dumb of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid of me: `first` and `second` are member variables, not methods, so:

```
/**
 * @brief UeOrdersModel::ueSlotRefreshOrdersData
 * @return  bool (true - success, false - error)
 */
bool UeOrdersModel::ueSlotRefreshOrdersData()
{
    QString userId=QString();
    QString placeId=QString();
    QString customerId=QString();
    bool result=false;

    if(this->ueLoggedUsersInfo()->ueNumberOfLoggedUsers()>0)
    {
        QMap<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>::const_iterator iterator=this->ueLoggedUsersInfo()->ueLoggedUsersData()->constBegin();
        userId=iterator.key().first;
        placeId=iterator.key().second;
        customerId=iterator.value();

        if(this->ueRefreshOrdersData(userId,
                                     placeId,
                                     customerId))
        {
            result=true;
        }   // if
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // ueSlotRefreshOrdersData
```

the upper code compiles!